# Laravel/Omnipay paypal, pass custom shipping amount

Tags: php, omnipay, paypal

I'm trying pass a custom shipping price to paypal express checkout.

I'm using omnipay and laravel 4.

I gather this is possible as referenced in the [paypal express docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/) but cant get it to work with omnipay Ive tried the following:

```
/*set api details*/
$request = $gateway->purchase([
    'amount'=> $cart['total'],
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'XXX' => 100
    'transactionId' => $order->reference,
    'returnUrl' => $returnURL . '/checkout/success',
    'cancelUrl' => $returnURL . '/checkout/cancel'
])->setItems($cart['items'])->send();

/*handleResponse*/
```

where XXX is shipping, shippingAmt, shipping_amount, I've tried adding shipping value to each item in the cart. I've tried modifying `abstractrequest.php` class  to add on a shipping value manually like so:

```
protected function getItemData()
    {
        $data = array();
        $items = $this->getItems();
        if ($items) {
            foreach ($items as $n => $item) {
                $data["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$n"] = $item->getName();
                $data["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC$n"] = $item->getDescription();
                $data["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY$n"] = $item->getQuantity();
                $data["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT$n"] = $this->formatCurrency($item->getPrice());
            }
        }
        $data["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT"] = "3.00";
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: According to the code the property is called 'shippingAmount': https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/blob/master/src/Message/AbstractRequest.php#L172 - So just replace 'XXX' with 'shippingAmount' and you should be good to go. No need to modify the AbstractRequest, it's being set in the AuthorizeRequest: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/blob/master/src/Message/ExpressAuthorizeRequest.php#L39

Answer (score 0):

I found the [answer here](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=shipping%20amount)

I was using an older version of package, so just needed to run composer update and could use the function `setShippingAmount();`